# Why is Lambda@Edge not forwarding to the correct bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have 3 S3 buckets:

- my-routing-test-ap-southeast-2
- my-routing-test-eu-west-2
- my-routing-test-us-east-1

They are all configured as a static website, with `block all public access` turned off and (example) this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Demo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-routing-test-us-east-1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have configured a cloudfront distribution with one origin:

- my-routing-test-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

And a `behaviour` configured for the origin above and `Legacy cache settings` header option set with the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` value.

I should point out here that [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders) for caching based on request header states:

> Specify whether you want CloudFront to cache objects based on the values of specified headers:

> Whitelist – CloudFront caches your objects based only on the values of the specified headers. Use Whitelist Headers to choose the headers that you want CloudFront to base caching on.

However, the `Edit behaviour` section of the CloudFront console shows the "Cache key and origin requests" options as:

`Legacy cache settings > Headers > Include the following headers > CloudFront-Viewer-Country`

Which, of course, does not appear to include the "Whitelist" option.

The distribution also has the `Origin request` set to the Lambda@Edge function (where the code is pulled from [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-S3-origin-request-trigger)):

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    const countryToRegion = {
        'US': 'us-east-1',
        'AU': 'ap-southeast-2',
        'GB': 'eu-west-2'
    };

    if (request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']) {
        const countryCode = request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].value;
        const region = countryToRegion[countryCode];
        
        console.log('countryCode: '+countryCode+' region: '+region);
        
        if (region) {
            console.log('region: '+region);
            request.origin.s3.region = region;
            const domainName = `my-routing-test-${region}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com`;
            request.origin.s3.domainName = domainName;
            console.log('request.origin.s3.domainName: '+domainName);
            request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: domainName }];
        }
    }

    callback(null, request);
};
```

When I call the cloudfront URL to retrieve my test file for my region (eu-west-2) I see this in my region's log group:

```
countryCode: GB region: eu-west-2
region: eu-west-2
request.origin.s3.domainName: origin-routing-eu-west-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

But the file is always the same image served from the `us-east-1` region. This should not be the case as each bucket contains a different image for each region.

What is missing or incorrect in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "Cache key and origin expiry" object caching was set to the default (1 year) and when I tested the initial file retrieval that basically store in the cache the primary origin file which could not get replaced by the regional version. Check your cache settings, folks!